# Как правильно оформить запрос на сервер?

Tags: javascript

Взял этот код с сайта, запрос отправляется по нажатию кнопке offerButton(он находится в div`е confirmModal).

Я не могу понять, как сделать, что бы можно было отправить этот же запрос введя js код в консоль браузера. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

```
    function offer(){inlineAlert("","Processing trade offer - please wait...");$("#confirmModal").modal("hide");var csv="";var sum=0;$("#right .slot").each(function(i,e){csv+=$(this).data("id")+",";
sum+=$(this).data("price");});
var turl=$("#tradeurl").val();
var remember=$("#remember").is(":checked")?"on":"off";
var url="scripts/_withdraw.php";
if(DEPOSIT){url="scripts/_deposit.php";}

$.ajax(
{
    "url":url,type:"GET",
    data:{"assetids":csv,"tradeurl":turl,"checksum":sum,"remember":remember},
    success:function(data){

    try{data=JSON.parse(data);
    if(data.success)
    {inlineAlert("success","New trade offer!");
    showPending(data);
    }else{
        inlineAlert("error",data.error);}}catch(err){inlineAlert("error","Javascript error: "+err);}},error:function(err){inlineAlert("error","AJAX error: "+err.statusText);
        },
    }
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  xhr.open('GET', 'index.html', false);  xhr.send()
```